# How to show some inputs?

Tags: angularjs

I have object nodes, that I iterate in `ng-repeat`.

Item of object in has `value` key and any value.

How to check if `item.value` is array and show values of array in inputs?

Otherwise show only one input with value is not array

My code:

https://jsfiddle.net/yf5fxs1k/3/

It looks not good, can I do this simplest in template?

Comment: You can check if a value is an array by doing `item.value.constructor === Array`.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but how to use `if else` in template with this condition?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated question with my code:

Comment: Can you add a Plunkr / JSFiffle or at least also show the code you use to invoke your `myCustomerVars` directive.

Comment: Yes, wait please

Comment: Look please: https://jsfiddle.net/yf5fxs1k/3/